# how to add space between two numbers

Tags: regex, notepad++, notepad

I have a huge number

> 37107287533902102798797998220837590246510135740250
>   46376937677490009712648124896970078050417018260538
>   74324986199524741059474233309513058123726617309629
>   91942213363574161572522430563301811072406154908250
>   23067588207539346171171980310421047513778063246676
>   89261670696623633820136378418383684178734361726757
>   28112879812849979408065481931592621691275889832738

Actually the number is quite bigger than that.

How do I put space between two numbers? How do I represent the same element + 'space' to be replaced in notepad?

Comment: By numbers do you mean digits?

Comment: I don't know how Matlab handles regex, but you can replace `(\d)` with ```\1 ```.

Comment: Let me see ... if i can do that with notepad++

Comment: It should work with ```\1 ```. If not, try ```$1 ```

Comment: I think that actually worked!!

Comment: if you like you can add it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replace `(\d)` with `\1 {pretend this is a space}`.

`\d` matches a single digit. `\1` refers to the first capturing group, which contains that digit.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying through notepad++. You can use inbuilt Macro feature

1. click on Macro>> Start recording

   Perform the action required for few occurrences(Ensure this pattern should match until end of file - In your case a space)
2. Macro >> Stop recording
3. Macro >> Run a Macro multiple times >> select - Run until end of file

This will easily fix.